# Select average time between two properties in elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch

Given an elasticsearch index with two date fields, how can I query for the average time between those two dates?

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "dateInserted": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "dateOptionalTime"
            },
            "dateUpdated": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "dateOptionalTime"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
[
    {
        "dateInserted": "2020-10-01 00:00:00",
        "dateUpdated": "2020-10-01 01:00:00"
    }, {
        "dateInserted": "2020-10-01 02:00:00",
        "dateUpdated": "2020-10-01 04:00:00"
    }
]
```

Interval for document A is one hour, interval for document B is two hours, therefore expected result would be 1.5 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An [`avg` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-avg-aggregation.html#_script) script should be fine:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "avg_duration": {
      "avg": {
        "script": {
          "source": """
            def duration = doc.dateUpdated.value.getMillis() - doc.dateInserted.value.getMillis();
            return duration / (float) (1000*60*60)
          """
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

or, more compact:

```
{
 ...
 "source": "def duration = doc.dateUpdated.value.getMillis() - doc.dateInserted.value.getMillis(); return duration / (float) (1000*60*60)"
 ...
}
```